# Kendo dropdownlist databound is called before dropdown item is set from the model

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I have recently started learning KendoUI and have come up with this issue. I am trying to include a dropdownlist in kendo grid using MVVM approach. The grid has 3 columns- Checkbox, text and dropdownlist. I want to manually set the dropdownlist value based on whether the checkbox is checked or not. As an example here i am trying to set the Class as 'Class 3' if checkbox is unchecked. Even though index is set to 2, it gets reverted back to the class from the model at the end of the event dataBound. Can anyone help me with this? I need to forcefully set the dropdown index. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="checkboxGrid">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsChecked" />         
</script>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="ddlGrid">
     <input data-role="dropdownlist"
        data-auto-bind="true"  
        data-text-field="name"
        data-value-field="id"
        data-auto-bind="true"
        data-bind="source: actionSource, value: class, events:{dataBound: dataBound }"/>
</script>

<div id="content" >
     <div id="my-grid"
          data-role="grid"
          data-sortable="true"
          data-selectable="true"
          data-columns='[
             {"field": "IsChecked", "title":" ", template: kendo.template($("#checkboxGrid").html())}, 
             {"field": "Name", "title":"Name" },
             {"field": "class", "title":"Class", template: kendo.template($("#ddlGrid").html())}
          ]'
          data-bind="source: dataSource">
     </div>
 </div>

 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {

        var viewModel = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
            dataSource: [
                {  IsChecked: true, Name: "Student 1", class: { name: "Class 1", id:"1" }},
                {  IsChecked: false, Name: "Student 2", class: { name: "-Please Select-", id:"999" } },
                {  IsChecked: false, Name: "Student 3", class: { name: "-Please Select-", id:"999" }},
                { IsChecked: true, Name: "Student 4", class: { name: "Class 3", id:"3" } }
            ],
            actionSource: [
                { name: "-Please Select-", id:"999"},
                { name: "Class 1", id:"1" },
                { name: "Class 2", id:"2" },
                { name: "Class 3", id:"3" }
            ],
            dataBound: function(e) {
                var ddl = e.sender;
                var gridRow = $(ddl.element).closest( "tr" );
                var checkbox = $(gridRow).find('input[type=checkbox]');
                debugger;
                if(checkbox.prop("checked") == false){
                  console.log("Checkbox checked : " + false);
                  //explicitly trying to set class to 'Class 3'
                  ddl.select(2);
                  debugger;
                }
                //Even though index is set to 2, it gets reverted back to the class from the model at the end of the event
            }
        });

        kendo.bind($('#my-grid'), viewModel);

      });
  </script>
```